# Gray scale to binary conversion

Tags: java

I am trying to convert grayscale image into binary. I tried the following code but it doesn't work. I am giving a piece of my code in which a grayscale image is set as `JLabel` icon which is to be converted into binary and again set as `JLabel` icon. Please help me find out my mistakes."

```
icon1 = l2.getIcon();
im = ((ImageIcon)icon1).getImage();
bi = new BufferedImage(im.getWidth(null), im.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
Graphics g = bi.createGraphics();
g.drawImage(im, 0, 0, null);
g.dispose();

for(int i=0; i<bi.getHeight(); i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<bi.getWidth(); j++)
    {
        Color c = new Color(bi.getRGB(j, i));
        if(c.getRed()<=125)
        {
            bi.setRGB(j, i, 0);
        }
        else if(c.getRed()>125)
        {
            bi.setRGB(j, i, 1);
        }
    }
}
icon= new ImageIcon(bi.getScaledInstance((panel2.getWidth())*15/15,(panel2.getHeight())*15/15, Image.SCALE_AREA_AVERAGING));
l4.setIcon(icon);
l4.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Please tell us, what "id doesn't work" means here. Are you getting an error message?

Comment: also, you dont need the "if (c.getRed()>125)" bit, the else already covers that exactly (it's either <= than 125 or > 125, no third options)

Comment: even if i am not giving that statement i dont get any output. when i set the pixel value to 0 in if statement and 1 in else statement it gives me a complete black image in the output.

Comment: i also tried to see what values are being set to all the pixels by using print statement, it prints 0 for all pixels values.

Comment: and thanks a lot sir for giving your precious time on my problem.